# How can I retrieve data of the past five weeks from a database table using SQL query

Tags: sql

I am trying to extract data from the past five weeks from a table using SQL query. I have a table named eth.blocks and columns named timestamp and gas_used. The column named timestamp consists of Unix dates. I am running the following query where I return those rows for which the difference between the current time and the timestamp is less than 5 weeks (3024000 seconds). When I check the Unix timestamps of the first and last row, I find out that the time range is much lesser than five weeks. What have I done wrong? How can I retrieve data from the table using SQL queries for the past five weeks? [I am adding the google colab notebook for your reference](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11oRWU9qSzbruEW-qZ9eXrl5HN1pX589L?usp=sharing).

```
stream_reader4 = spice.query('select "timestamp", gas_used from eth.blocks where ((%s) -"timestamp") < 3024000'%(current_time))
```

Comment: In terms of dates, not all the database engines handle the same functions, so you need to specify what's yours (oracle, sql server, mysql, ...)

Comment: Also please share some sample data (perhaps a timestamp that is before and another after the last 5 weeks. Lastly, please share the value for `current_time` variable or the code where you generate that.

Comment: @James This is a sql database

Comment: @JNevill Yes, I have added the code in the google colab notebook, the link to which is provided in the question.

Comment: Again, what database/rDBMS is this? Can you do an `ORDER BY timestamp`. It could be that all of the expected dates are in there and your "first" and "last" records and representative of start/end for the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a small "l" for long, after the 3024000.
Like this:
< 3024000l'%(current_time))
Does that help?

Comment: No, it shows a parsing error.

Comment: We can figure it out. What database are you using? MySQL, Oracle or something like that?